# Why this useFormik is updating the initial value by itself?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cron, formik

I got component structure like this. The actual code is not like this I am just trying to help you visualize.

```
<EditAssessment>
     <AssessmentForm>
       <AssessmentScheduleCronWeekField>
       </AssessmentScheduleCronWeekField>
     </AssessmentForm>
</EditAssessment>
```

The thing is when I pass the value from `EditAssessment` to child component, `useformMik` is changing the value.

```
EditAssessment component


// logging the initial value
       {console.log(
          (study.phases[Number(phaseIndex)] as AssessmentPhase).assessments[
            Number(assessmentIndex)
          ]
       )}
        {loading ? (
          <Loading size="large" label="Saving..." />
        ) : (
          <AssessmentForm
            initialValues={
              (study.phases[Number(phaseIndex)] as AssessmentPhase).assessments[
                Number(assessmentIndex)
              ] as Assessment
            }
            onSubmit={onSubmit}
            onCancel={onDone}
          />
        )}
```

Here is the `AssessmentForm component`

```
import { Field, FormikProvider, useFormik } from 'formik';

export const AssessmentForm = ({
  initialValues,
  onSubmit,
  onCancel,
}: AssessmentFormProps) => {
  const [scheduleType, setScheduleType] = useState('empty');
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues,
    onSubmit,
    validationSchema,
  });
  // *** THE VALUE CHANGE HERE, THIS IS IMPORTANT ***
  console.log(initialValues.schedule);
  console.log(formik.values.schedule);

  return (
    <FormikProvider value={formik}>
      <Form data-cy="assessment-form" onSubmitCapture={formik.handleSubmit}>
        {/* Assessment Questionnaire ID Field */}
        <Field name="questionnaireId" component={AssessmentQuestionIdField} />
        <div>Hello</div>
        {/* Assessment Schedule Type Form */}
        <AssessmentScheduleTypeForm
          assessmentSchedule={initialValues.schedule}
          onTypeChange={setScheduleType}
        />
        <div>Hello 1</div>

        {/* Various Assessment Schedule Forms */}
        {(() => {
          let component = undefined;
          switch (scheduleType) {
            case 'oneTime':
              component = AssessmentScheduleOneTimeField;
              break;
            case 'cronWeek':
              component = AssessmentScheduleCronWeekField;
              break;
          }
          if (component !== undefined) {
            return <Field name="schedule" component={component} />;
          }
          return (
            <Empty
              image={Empty.PRESENTED_IMAGE_SIMPLE}
              description={<p>Select a Schedule Type</p>}
            />
          );
        })()}

        <AssessmentFormScheduleDescription schedule={initialValues.schedule} />
        {/* Combined Form using `useFormik() */}

        
      </Form>
    </FormikProvider>
  );
};
```

As you can see there are two `console.log` statement places 1 in `EditAssement` and `in`AssessmentForm`

The value passing to the `AssessmentForm` change automatically and idk why

Here is a screen shot

[image]

These console.log when I reach to the path. If you line 53 console.log is coming from `useformMik` and that one is updating the value

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is an issue with formik, I tried to make a similar [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-cookies-20eie6?file=/src/Basic.js), but I dont see issues with passing props, original values do arrive in the child component. Of course I dont see all of your code, like what are these new values, where do they come from, maybe you can investigate on that.
As last resort you can remove `useFormik` and write your own context state, as useFormik is nothing more than advanced context state [doc1](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormik#useformikvaluesconfig-formikconfigvalues-formikpropsvalues), [doc2](https://formik.org/docs/tutorial#leveraging-react-context).